# Jaxb Element Attribute Choice

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

is there any trick to have two element attributes defined, which excludes each other
(similar like choice) ?
I know to make it on elements but not on attributes.

```
@XmlAttribute(name="firstName") 
private String firstName ;
@XmlAttribute(name="lastName") 
private String lastName ;
```

For example, either element firstName="" or element lastName="" is valid,
but not element firstName="" lastName=""

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no attribute choice. You'll need to convert them to full-fledged elements.

Answer (score 0):

If the value mapped with `@XmlAttribute` is `null` then it won't be marshaled to XML.  You can combine this with some of your own custom logic to get the result you are looking for.